# Getting null NSString after assigning

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableDictionary which contains key/value pairs, when I tried to debug the content it seems that is loaded correctly:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"title"]);//result: iOS in 24 hours.
```

but when I tried to assign this value to another NSString I get a null value

```
NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];// even tried to cast it using (NSString*)
NSLog(@"%@",title);//null value
```

Comment: You're telling me you have both those statements, one above the other in the same place in your code, and one gives you a value and the other a null??  (I don't believe you.)

Comment: This can't be reproduced with the sample provided.

Comment: @HotLicks I swear come on do you think that I'm posting to have fun?

Comment: @CrimsonChris I can't post the hole code as it's too long and split on multiple classes.

Comment: Do you think we're here to read your mind?

Comment: How do you expect us to answer your question if you won't post the code in context? HotLicks was trying to point out that your question is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: Post the code where you are declaring item and if it is declared in both classes

Comment: Is your dictionary an `assign`/`weak` property assigned from another view controller? You might want to check if it's being released due to that. If it is indeed a property, try making it a `strong` property. However, this might **not** be the solution, but just a way to debug.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images, but here's a link to check that the dictionary is not empty. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nUIs7JwP93U3luSlpsVjN3VHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @n00bProgrammer I have a JSON array and I'm using NSJSONSerialization to decode it and assign the result to an NSArray (@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableDictionary *lunchMealsOpportunities;) which contain an NSMutableDictionary for each object.

Comment: Paste the important code segments into your question -- don't give us links.

Answer (score 0):

Check like this below:-

```
if (item[@"title"] == [NSNull null])
{
//your code
}
```